# How to I turn off plain text mode when using google forms to send an email?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email, google-apps-script

I'm in the final stage of developing a script for a google form I've created to send emails to specific people based on form submission. I want the email to be well laid out and readable by all those who will receive it. In order to do that I just need to insert HTML tags into the email content, but no matter which way I go about it the tags come through on the final email. I think the issue is that the email being sent through the GmailApp.sendEmail() function is being processed as plain text.

I'd be happy to just have some bold tags come through. That's all.

Method 1:

```js
var emailContent = 
        a2 + ' submitted a Family Visit Form on ' + a1 + '.\n' +
        'Please review the following information:\n\n\n' + //a1 outputs the date
                     
                     
         q2.bold() + ': ' + a2 + '\n\n' + 
         q3 + ': ' + a3 + '\n\n' +
         q4 + ': ' + a4 + '\n\n';
```

Method 2

```js
var emailContent = 
        a2 + ' submitted a Family Visit Form on ' + a1 + '.\n' +
        'Please review the following information:\n\n\n' + //a1 outputs the date
                     
                     
         '<strong>' + q2 + '</strong>' + ': ' + a2 + '\n\n' + 
         '<strong>' + q3 + '</strong>' + ': ' + a3 + '\n\n' +
         '<strong>' + q4 + '</strong>' + ': ' + a4 + '\n\n';
```

The actual code has a lot more lines but this gives you the idea. Nothing seems to work. The email always produces the tags.

For example the end product always looks like this:

```html
Jonny Boy submitted a Family Visit Form on Sun Oct 18 2020 19:41:14 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time).
Please review the following information:


<b>What is your first and last name?</b>: Jonny Boy
```

..and so on, and so on.

I've toggled the switch in Gmail so that emails sent from this account won't come through as plain text. Beyond that I don't know what to do. I've scoured the internet and have turned up nothing for this error.

Please help!

Comment: Can I ask you about your script for sending email using `GmailApp.sendEmail`?